# How to Deactivate Auto Delete of Mails in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

When ever we sent a Sale Order by Mail, after sending the mail gets deleted automatically. But, i want to keep those mails after sent also. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Activate Technical features for Administrator User.
Then goto Settings menu --> Email --> Templates , then search for  Sales Order - Send by Email . For that record Click on Advanced Settings tab and UN-check Auto Delete option.

Comment: After un-checking and sending email it automatically becomes checked.
What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that before sending the email:

```
template_values = {'auto_delete': False}
template.write(template_values)
```